# Difference between Component based and inheritance based Architecture Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

What is the Difference between Component based and inheritance based Architecture Unity3d ?
Can anybody Explain me with an Example code.How to implement it in Game ?

Comment: google for **object oriented** instead of inheritance based. also those terms are NOT mutually exlusive, they describe different things.

Comment: Doesn't this sound lot like homework?

Comment: The main difference is Unity costs about $3000 a year.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure of the exact differences in unity, but I think I can explain it generally.

**Component Artchitecture**

You have your basic `Entity` class, which can have components. Components like HealthComponent, which would hold the entities HP, MeshComponent which would hold the entities mesh, FreeMoveComponent, which would randomly move the entity around, AttackComonent, which would cause the entity to attack others etc.

To build a random "mob", like a cow, you would give the entity the HealthComponent, FreeMoveComponent and the MeshComponent. That would create a mob that can be killed and moves around. To create an enemy, you could use all of the components for the cow, plus the Attack component. Now you have something that can attack you, has HP and moves.

**Inheritance Architecture**

You have your base `Entity` class. Then, to achieve something similar to what I explained above, you would create a Mob class, that would extend the Entity class. You would add it a HP count and a Mesh.

Then, you would create two other classes - MovingMob and Enemy. You would implement the code for free moving to the MovingMob, give it the cow mesh and you have a cow. Now, to create the enemy, you would have it extend the MovingMob, because you want it to move to and add it the code to attack others.

Comment: indeed.  basically "component" based systems fit naturally with "agent" thinking.  the OP can google up "ECS" which is a bogus term someone invented more or less to describe Unity and other scene-based game engines.

Comment: Thank you for such a nice Explanation...

Comment: Glad you liked it. If this answer is sufficient for you, please, mark it as the accepted answer so that this question can be closed. Thank you.